# How can I remove '\n' from strings in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I read text from my database which is SQL Server.

In the database the text looks OK.

But when I read the text in C# from database it comes with `\n` to represent New Line

The problem is that I have to Substring that text based on pre-determined numbers.

Example

Find the word at position from 29 to 31

This should return `Yes`

In the database I have this text

```
Hi
How are you?
Are you Ok?
Yes Thanks.
```

I get the text as follow in C#

```
Hi\nHow are you?\nAre you Ok?\nYes Thanks.
```

When I get to find the word at position from 29 to 31 I get `\nY`

How can I fix the new line and other chars such as Tab in this text?

Comment: The newline is likely there in the database as well. The database tooling is just hiding it from you.

Comment: If you want more details (but trust me my earlier comment is almost certainly correct) then please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Does `\n` *literally* appear in the string?

Comment: @JohnyL Yes it shows as 2 char \n

Comment: Really strange since these are invisible characters.

Comment: You would have to ackknowledge your \n's during count. Instead of "29 to 31" try something like "32 to 34". It would be a problem, if those \n's and questions are dynamic, but I do believe there are always 3 \n right?

Comment: I'd suggest we not engage with the question further until we see a [mcve]. Since without it, we are guessing. And if we are going to do that, my first comment is almost certainly the right guess. ;)

Comment: Could you show in Debugger window what this string variable holds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Regex to replace the parts you dislike.

```
        String input = "Hi\nHow are you?\nAre\tyou Ok?\nYes Thanks.";
        String output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\s", " ");
```

`\s` is the pattern that matches any whitespace character. This replacement replaces all whitespace characters with a single space `" "`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed position (like 29 to 31) and do not know what is at this point, i would use:

```
yourString = yourString.Replace("\n", "");
```

If you know the word I would work with

```
yourString.IndexOf("Yes");
```

and

```
yourString.Substring(startPosition, endPosition);
```

startPosition = IndexOf result,
endPosition = IndexOf result + string length